# Are these words at all on the wall?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, connect-wall

I was walking in a strange hallway and stumbled on an even stranger wall.  What are these? Are these words? And what are the 4 groups they go into?

[image: strangely looking wall]

Hint:

> I also found a shelf with books in the hallway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The symbols on the wall are ...

> ... English words written in a sustitution cipher that replaces letters with symbols. There are different glyphs for capital and small letters and there is no visual similarity between corresponding small letters and caps. (That's a nasty move: It precludes finding a simple substitution and then run the text through a cryptogram solver.)
>
>  The code is best tackled by looking at words that have repeated letters and running the letter patterns through a dictionary search. The first word, for example, might be Million, Kissing or Ballads among others, but the second word is almost certainly Believe or Relieve. After some words have been identified, the remaining words become more obvious, but it was tough to get a foot in the door. Of course, once you have found some words you can start to make use of the capital letters, too, which seem to have the pattern that letters that differn only in diacritics are adjacent letters in the English alphabet.

The resulting wall is:

> `.        _________   _________   _________   _________`
>  `.`
>  `.         Fallacy     Believe      Decor        Salt`
>  `.        _________   _________   _________   _________`
>  `.`
>  `.          Sword        Ice        Razor      Curtain`
>  `.        _________   _________   _________   _________`
>  `.`
>  `.          Chair      Poison        Gun       Imagine`
>  `.        _________   _________   _________   _________`
>  `.`
>  `.          Jump        Stage       Glass      Diamond`
>  `.        _________   _________   _________   _________`

and I believe the groups are:

> **Imagine**, **Jump**, **Believe** and **Poison** are songs by John Lennon, Van Halen, Justin Bieber and Alice Cooper.
>
>  Aristotle's **Fallacy**, Chechov's **Gun**, Occam's **Razor** and the **Sword** of Damocles are named after people.
>
>  **Diamond**, **Ice**, **Glass** and **Salt** are crystals.
>
>  Finally, **Decor**, **Stage**, **Chair** and **Curtain** can be found in a theatre. (They could just be items of interior design, but that would leave the stage unaccounted for.)

Comment: Is the hint for group two?

Comment: Great job! Now there is only a tiny mix-up. The first group is indeed in the category you said, but there is one item that does not go there. It goes in the second category which is not what you think it is. And the hint was not for group two - it was related to solving the symbols. But I can see that you did that without it.

Comment: I see. I guess Poison (by Kiss) goes into the first group instead of Fallacy and then the second group is things named after people: Occam's razor, Chechov's gun, Aristotle's fallacy and Damocles's sword?

Comment: Yes. That's it. Although I did have another fallacy and sword in mind but this doesn't change the group. :)

Comment: Which ones did you have in mind?

Comment: @MOehm, McNamara's fallacy and Newton’s flaming laser sword. But the group stays the same either way. :) And Believe is a song by Cher - but this also doesn't change the group. :)

Comment: @MariaDeleva: Aha, thanks. I didn't know either, but the Wikipedia page for McNamara's fallacy conveniently lists the whole group in the "See also" section. `:)`

Comment: There is another convenient thing you could have used instead of trying to break the cipher and I thought someone would figure it out, but I guess it is sweeter being able to solve it this way :) I have done it before with some not properly encoded Unicode text and it was fun. :)

Comment: @MariaDeleva: But that would require to know the Unicode codes of all glyphs, wouldn't it? And I have a hard time to find most of them. Some don't even seem to exist like the upstide-down triple asterisk and the equals sign with two dots.

Comment: @MOehm - nope. It is actually a font - Bookshelf Symbol 7. (that was what the hint was referring to).

Comment: @MariaDeleva: Okay, now the hint makes sense. That would have been a convenient shortcut indeed, but I've never come across that font. (It's installed on my computer, but I've never noticed it. It's a strange collection of symbols that I don't find useful.) I found solving the cipher by hand rather tough, probably because I wanted the a's in Fallacy to be i's at first.

Answer (score 0):

I've found

> 29 different characters, so even if it is a direct character-letter conversion, there is some additional trick how to convert them into the 26 -letter alphabet. Or they represent not (only) letters.

Comment: Keep digging. :)

Comment: There are two groups of symbols depending on the position in the "word": The first symbol in each cell looks like a letter (or IPA symbol) with a diacritical mark and the rest are non-letter-like symbols. (So the first set might just be capital latters.)

Comment: @MOehm, your assumption is correct.